# Create sum of multiple sums

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

In my app, there are three `tableView` which are hierarchical,ach in a separat `VC`. Clubs -> Members -> Transactions. I want to add at the club `tableView` a label, where the amount of all transactions of the members in this club are. I did this already with the start amount of the members and now I want to count the amount of all transactions of a member and count these amounts, so I have the amount of all transactions in this club.

Here is what I did with the start amount:

```swift
var countmember = 0.0
  for membs in (club.members)! {
     countmember = membs.saldo + countmember
        }
```

#### My try

Now I have to access all transactions and count them together and then count all those counts together. I tried something like this but this did not work.

```swift
var transcount = 0.0

        if let transactions = member?.transactions {
            for trans in transactions {
                transcount = trans.money + transcount
            }
        }
        var transmemcount = 0.0
        for _ in members {
            transmemcount = transcount + transmemcount
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you really want to summarize.
But, e.g., for the first loop you can use `reduce` method:

```
let countmember = (club.members)!.reduce(0.0) {
return $0 + membs.saldo
}
```

Or for the second two loops inside each other. Or reduce too:

```
let transmemcount = 0.0

for member in members {
for trans in member.transactions {
transmemcount += trans.money
}
}
```

Comment: I want to summarize the transactions of all member in a club. Si just the amount of all those. The function to summarize the member.saldo I already have in my first code part in the question.

Comment: Oh yes it worked. I just had to make transmemcount to a var and make members to club.members! and unwrap transactions. Very great thank you :D